# How to link route using vue-bottom-navigation bar?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have used the vue-bottom-navigation to import the swipe navigation bar from https://vue-bottom-navigation.netlify.app/guide/swipe, I tried adding a router link to one of the icons using the guide on the netlify web, didn't work, then tried using router-link which also isn't working, anyone know what's going on here?:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="min-h-screen flex flex-col sm:justify-center items-center pt-6 sm:pt-0 bg-orange-100">
            <div>
                <Link href="/">
                <ApplicationLogo class="w-20 h-20 fill-current text-gray-500" />
                </Link>
            </div>
            <div>
                <slot />
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Bottom navigation -->
        <SwipeBottomNavigation :options="options" v-model="selected"
            style=" --swiper-color: #CE9F41; --icon-color: #CE9F41">
            <template #icon="{ props }">
                <FontAwesomeIcon :icon="props.icon" />
            </template>
            <template #title="{ props }">
                <b>{{ props.title }}</b>
            </template>
        </SwipeBottomNavigation>
    </div>
</template>
```

**attempt with router-link**

```
<SwipeBottomNavigation :options="options" v-model="selected" style="--swiper-color: #CE9F41; --icon-color: #CE9F41">
  <template #icon="{ props }">
    <router-link :to="props.path">
      <FontAwesomeIcon :icon="props.icon" />
    </router-link>
  </template>
  <template #title="{ props }">
    <b>{{ props.title }}</b>
  </template>
</SwipeBottomNavigation>
```

```js
<script setup>
import ApplicationLogo from '@/Components/ApplicationLogo.vue';
import { Link } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { SwipeBottomNavigation } from 'bottom-navigation-vue';
import 'bottom-navigation-vue/dist/style.css';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css';
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
// import { useRoute, useRouter, RouterLink } from 'vue-router';


const selected = ref(1);
const options = [
    { id: 1, icon: ['fas', 'comment'], title: 'Messages', path: '/messages'},
    { id: 2, icon: ['fas', 'heart'], title: 'Saved Coaches' },
    { id: 3, icon: ['fas', 'trophy'], title: 'Explore' },
    { id: 4, icon: ['fas', 'clipboard-check'], title: 'Timetable' },
    { id: 5, icon: ['fas', 'circle-user'], title: 'Profile' },
];

</script>
```

I've tried linking using the path name, using router-link, link, vue-router. It just doesn't link to anything

Comment: For change route you can add path field to your option items like below :
Note : your path field must be an Object.

[
  {
    id: 1,
    icon: "fas fa-wallet",
    title: "Wallet",
    path: { name: "bookmarks", query: { bookmark: "important" } },
  },
];

Comment: moon's example comes straight from the [documentation](https://vue-bottom-navigation.netlify.app/guide/swipe/#route) btw

Comment: i tried that before but it doesn’t link anything when clicked

Comment: Are you having any warning/error in the console?